# Python, why do we have to inherit from 'list' class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm learning object oriented python and came across this issue where python is forcing me to inherit from built-in 'list' class to use append method.

```
class ContactSearch(list):                  #Why inherit from 'list'?
    def search(self, name):
        matching_contact = []
        for contact in self:
            if name in contact.name:
                matching_contact.append(contact)
        return matching_contact
```

Why can't I simply declare an empty list and append to it? For example it works find in the following code without inheriting from 'list class':

```
class Contact:
    all_contacts = []

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        Contact.all_contacts.append(self)
```

Comment: What do you expect `self` to be?  Is your class storing data?  If so, how?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. What I'm trying to understand is that in these two different classes, what is the difference in these two:

matching_contact = [] and 
all_contacts = []

Isn't both declaring an empty list?

Comment: The problem is the line `for contact in self:`  This requires the class you are writing to support iteration.  When you inherit from `list`, you inherit the iteration built in to `list`

Comment: Thanks, I think you answered it very well.

Answer (score 0):

In ContactSearch, `matching_contact` is temporary variable for result of searching. A instance of ContactSearch is list. So search method can use `self` in iterator. `matching_contact` is over when search method is done.

In Contact, `all_contacts` is class variable and all instance of Contact share this. Instance of Contact is NOT list. But you can access all contact using like `Contact.all_contacts`, and yes, it is list.

The difference is only where the data is stored. The one stores data in itself, and the another stores data in its variable.